# Instantiate a web service, <name> is a namespace but it is used as a type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, namespaces, instantiation

**Using:** 
Visual Studio 2017
Windows 10
C#
App Windows Form (.NET Framework) project type

**Contest:**
I'm trying to make a classic desktop windows form app that can consume a web service

**Dynamics and problem:**
I follow those steps: create a new project -> right click on the project -> select "Add" -> select "Add a Service Reference..." -> paste the WS link page in Address text box -> press "Go" -> press "OK"

The default name of WS namespace is ServiceReference1, it appears under Connected Services menù.

Then here you are my basic code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1 echo = new ServiceReference1();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Form_Load I instantiate my WS.

The error:

```
'ServiceReference1' is a namespace but it is used as a type
```

Searching this error I've seen it happens when you declare a namespace name = same namespace inside class name, but this case shouldn't have nothing to do whit that, cause I've not delcared any class.

Thanks for help.

Comment: When you reference a service, Visual Studio creates the web service stub classes. And as you already mentioned; `ServiceReference1` is the namespace of this class, which is set by Visual Studio. Check for a class named `ServiceReference1.****Client`. That is the actual web service client you need to instantiate.

Comment: You can refer to Oguz's advice. By the way, if your class name is the same as your namespace name, you can use the code ServiceReference1.ServiceReference1 echo = new ServiceReference1.ServiceReference1(); or using ServiceReference1 in the left -top.